# Count number of times an individual performed specific task in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From `excel` file, i have a `dataframe`:

```
df
       personID     Task_1  Task_2  ...  Task_n  
0      1035         50.5      49.5  ...      64.0        
1                   NaN       NaN  ...       NaN        
2                   NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       
3                   NaN       Inc  ...       NaN       
4      1026         61.0      47.0  ...      61.0        
5                   61.0      39.0  ...      20.0       
6                   NaN       NaN  ...       NaN       
7                   NaN       NaN  ...       NaN  
8                   NaN       NaN  ...       NaN        
9      1032         45.5      45.0  ...      60.0
       ...          ...       ...
```

Persons were awarded scores for completing a task, Inc indicates the task was not completed.
I will like to count the number of times a task was completed and awarded (ignore NaN).
Thus, I aim to get :

```
personID     Task_1  Task_2  ...  Task_n
1035          1       1             1
1026          2       2             2
1032          1       1             1
....          ....
```

How can this be accomplished? (not necessary in this tabular format).
I did this:

**step 1:**
reduced the `df` into 3 `columns`:

`df_2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["personID"])`

```
        personID file_name unit
0       1035     Task_1    51
1       1035     Task_1   NaN
2       1035     Task_1   NaN
3       1035     Task_1   NaN
4       1026     Task_1   61
..             ...       ...  ...
        1035     Task_2   49.5
        1035     Task_2   NaN
```

**Step 2:**

```
for i in df_2.personID:
    ind_lst = []
    print(i)
    ind = df_2.loc[df_2['personID'] == i, ('file_name','unit')]
    
    for index, row in (ind).iterrows():
        lst= [row.file_name, row.unit]
        ind_lst.append(lst)
           
    for t in ind_lst:
        h = 0
        for m in newlst_2:
            if t[0] == m:
                h +=1
    print(t,h)
Note: newlst_2 = [task_1, task_2, ..., task_n]
```

I get:

```
1035
['Task_1', 50.5] 1
1035
['Task_1', nan] 1
1035
['Task_1', nan] 1
1035
['Task_1', nan] 1
1026
['Task_1', 61.0] 1
1026
['Task_1', 61.0] 1
1026
['Task_1', Nan] 1
```

Comment: Can you explain the output of `Task_2` for person id `1035`? How'd you got `1`?

Comment: whats wrong with groupby on your melted df ? `pd.melt(df,id_vars='personID',var_name='task').groupby(['task','personID']).count()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, from the `df`, the column `Task_2` for `1035` has one entry, 49.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
m = df.loc[:, 'Task_1':].replace('Inc', np.nan).notna()
counts = m.groupby(df['personID'], sort=False).sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
# print(counts)

   personID  Task_1  Task_2  Task_n
0      1035     1.0     1.0     1.0
1      1026     2.0     2.0     2.0
2      1032     1.0     1.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your personID column has an id in each row (not visible in your example), you can use groupby :

```py
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'personID': [1,1,1,2,2], 
                   'Task_1': [12,87,345,22,32], 
                   'Task_2': [12,np.nan,np.nan,22,32]})

# to get the count per person and per task
df.groupby('personID').count()

# to get the count per task
df.drop(columns='personID').count()
```

If your personID column has missing values and you wish to fill between two ids, you can use

```py
df['personID'] = df.personID.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: there are no id row. Is it a requirement for `groupby` to give consistent results?

Comment: You can use any column to do the groupby. Id would usually be unique, and therefore useless for a groupby. Groupby is useful to aggregate data sharing common values in a column